# How to implement HTTPS in DataSnap?

Tags: rest, delphi, https, c++builder, datasnap

I am trying to create HTTPS secured DataSnap WebBroker application in C++ Builder, but I am unable to do so. First I created self-signed OpenSSL certificate by using the following command line:

**openssl req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365**

When creating new DataSnap WebBroker (VCL) application I checked HTTPS and selected certificate file, key file and password in the wizard. I clicked "Test" inside a wizard and everything is OK (test passed). When running the application I start the server without errors, but when testing it inside a web browser I get:

URL: https://localhost:8080/

Chrome: **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**

Firefox: **SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP**

When I create a separate REST (VCL) client application and make a request I get the following error:
**REST request failed: Error getting Server Certificate**

Why is this happening and how to fix it so that I can have a secure (HTTPS) connection? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else will have a similar problem: I solved this by creating self-signed certificate in IIS and then bind it to HTTPS protocol inside IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use TLS 1.2 when using the REST client libraries in **10.2 Tokyo**.

```
RESTClient.SecureProtocols := [THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS12];
```

But using a new VCL forms DataSnap server from the wizard, when I access the sample method from Chrome using this URL:

```
https://localhost:62032/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/ABC
```

I get the Chrome error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH as you saw.

We also have Delphi 10.4 for FireMonkey cross-platform development, so I created a VCL forms DataSnap server using that.

Using the above URL, I get this error in the IDE:

```
First chance exception at $77C2C3A2. Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message
'Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version'.
Process Project21.exe (17080)
```

Turns out that **10.4 Sydney** added a `SSLVersion` property to the `TDSCertFiles` component but that it defaults to *sslvTLSv1*.

Changing it to *sslvTLSv1_2* allows the above test URL to work fine using HTTPS on **Chrome** and **Edge**.